# Getting a Simple Javascript Function to Work

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to get a simple javascript function to work. I know enough Javascript to think to myself, "This should work, Why isn't it working!" I'm sure we've all been there before. I have done some research to brush up on my functions and to compare my function to but to no avail, I still can't get this function to work. I'm using Javascript to try to display my name within a span element. Normally this should be easy but, for some reason it just isn't working. This is also done in a .php file and a .html file. Because i wanted to make sure it didn't matter if it was a .php file or .html file. It won't work in either. This is for a php project by the way.
Here's the code

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var yourName = "Robin";
function placeName()
{
    document.getElementById("myName").innerHTML = yourName;
}   
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>PHP Basics</h1>
    <h2>Hi! My Name is<span id = "myName"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Like I said, This should be simple, but it won't work. I'm hoping a new set of eyes (you guys) would be able to point out my rookie mistake. If I need to explain anything in more detail please let me know. And thank you all very much.

Comment: Where are You executing the function ?

Comment: The function `placeName()` is declared but isn't executed anywhere. Try to execute it in a `window.onload` or `document.onload` statement.

Comment: Minor note: You never closed your `<h2>` tag.

Comment: @Mike C. Thank you for pointing that out (</h2>). The placeName function should be executed in the span element with the id of "myName" with document.getElementById("myName").innerHTML = yourName;

Comment: @RobinJennings `<span>`s don't execute functions. You need to either call that function from somewhere else in your code or setup an event handler, such as a click event, to call that function for you.

Answer (score 6):

You're not running the function.  Be careful, only run the function after the span has been created or else it will not work.  See this example.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    var yourName = "Robin";

    function placeName()
    {
        document.getElementById("myName").innerHTML = yourName;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>PHP Basics</h1>
    <h2>Hi! My Name is<span id = "myName"></span>
    <script>
    // run function
    placeName();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

You have made the body of the function but you haven't call the function so that it will be executed. You can do it like this

```
<html> 
<head> 
</head> <body> <h1>PHP Basics</h1> <h2>Hi! My Name is<span id = "myName"></span> </body> </html>
```

var
     yourName = "Robin"; 
     function    placeName() {
    document.getElementById
      ("myName").innerHTML 
      = yourName; }

```
placeName();
```

// it won't return undefined try it

Comment: This would execute too soon and the getById would return undefined. You also haven't added anything that isn't already in the upvoted answer.

Comment: After your edit it will no longer give undefined (if you added some script tags) but you still haven't added anything that isn't already in the upvoted, and formatted, answer.